# Getting 2 Notice: Undefined Variable errors

Tags: undefined

The two errors are as below:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: HawA_Homes in C:\wamp\www\HawA_CIS241\InsertRecord.php on line 48

Notice: Undefined variable: HawA_Homes in C:\wamp\www\HawA_CIS241\InsertRecord.php on line 56
```

I've checked my names and they appear correct and I am not sure how to proceed now.
Code is as below:

```
<?php           
    $hostName = "localhost";
    $databaseName = "test";
    $userName = "root";
    $password = "";
    $tableName = "HawA_Homes";

    //try to connect report error if cannot
    $db = new mysqli($hostName, $userName, $password, $databaseName) or die(" Could not connect:" .   mysql_error());
    print(" Connection successful to host $hostName <br /> <br />"); //report connection success

    //Get data to create a new record
    $Address = $_REQUEST["address"];
    $DateBuilt = $_REQUEST["dateBuilt"];
    $Value = $_REQUEST["value"];
    $Size = $_REQUEST["size"];
    $Number_of_floors = $_REQUEST["floors"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $HawA_Homes('Address','DateBuilt','Value','Size','Number_of_floors')VALUES{'$Address','$DateBuilt','$Value','$Size','$Number_of_floors')"; //Create insert query for new record

    //try to query dataase / store returned results and report error if not successful
    if(!$result =$db->query($sql))
    {
    //die('There was an error running the query[' .$db->error . ']';
    }

    print("SQL query $sql successful to database: $HawA_Homes <br /><br />"); //report sql query successful.                
    ?>
```

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why it was edited or what was changed?....@sunil sonune

Comment: Attempted to edit my comment for more info but the edit apparently does not allow adding new lines. Not sure what I was supposed to research or look for, a comment pointing me in the right direction would have been helpful.

Comment: Just keep voting it down and don't inform me why. I'll go to another site from now on then. Maybe it will be a bit more user friendly with informing users how it wants things formatted

Answer (score 0):

You have these notices because the variable `$HawA_Homes` isn't declared in your code before being used at line 48 and 56. (These are just notices, they are not critical errors, you can avoid displaying them by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` at the begining of your code, like [explained here](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php))

In fact, you used `$HawA_Homes` instead of `$tableName` in these lines. Replace them, you won't have notices anymore for these lines.